# resolve a variable in GitLab CI's variable clause

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci, regex-group

I have a scenarios where I need to push a feature branch's commit to an environment for testing. There are few environments and a developer has a choice to push to any ENV based on the commit message.

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\/CONN-*/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^*Enterprise_1.*$/
      variables:
        Name_Tag: "Enterprise_1"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\/CONN-*/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^*Enterprise_2.*$/
      variables:
        Name_Tag: "Enterprise_2"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\/CONN-*/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^*Enterprise_3.*$/
      variables:
        Name_Tag: "Enterprise_3"
```

So if a commit message contains a string with "Enterprise_2", then deployment will go to "Enterprise_2" environment. likewise depending on Enterprise_X, an Enterprise_X env will be picked.
I searched if capture groups are supported on gitlab, but couldn't find any documentation.

Also i tried the below:-

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\/CONN-*/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^*Enterprise_[1-9].*$/
      variables:
        Name_Tag: 'if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ ^.*(Enterprise_[1-9])(.*)$ ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi'
```

But this sets Name_Tag variable to literal "if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ ^.*(Enterprise_[1-9])(.*)$ ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi".

could you please advise on a solution.

Comment: The regex `^.*(Enterprise_[1-9])(.*)$` will match two groups, one for `Enterprise_1` and one for all other characters after that, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/Oyz1BC/2). Was that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rules` are not really meant to be used to set variables. As the [reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) states:

```
Use rules to include or exclude jobs in pipelines.
```

---

For this situation `before_script` step should be used:

```
job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\/CONN-*/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^*Enterprise_[1-9].*$/
  before_script:
    - >
      if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "^.*(Enterprise_[1-9]).*$" ]]; then
        NAME_TAG=$(BASH_REMATCH[1]);
      fi
  script:
    - echo $NAME_TAG
```

First, we are going to have only one rule, for branches in `feature/CONN-x` format, and whose commit message has `Enterprise_x` string. Since we are sure that commit message has desired string we can extract it in `before_script`. If the regex is matched, set `NAME_TAG` to the value of the captured group.

---

If for any reason `BASH_REMATCH` isn't working for you, like it (still) isn't working for me, you can try `sed`. Match group you need, and substitute everything before and after the group:

```
job:
  before_script:
    - NAME_TAG=$(echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | sed -r "s/^.*(Enterprise_[1-9]).*$/\1/")
```